# How to trim leading spaces while importing Excel into mysql

Tags: php, mysql, excel, import, trim

i am importing a CSV file into mysql database. One whole column (Project_ID_) in the excel sheet has leading space in it and after importing, the space is converted into garbage value in mysql table. 
For example: 
Value in Excel is :  **000000000015382**
Value in Mysql becomes: **� 000000000015382**

how do i trim the space

code for importing is given below:

```
$import="INSERT INTO streammapping(Project_ID_Numeric
,Project_ID_ 
,Project_Description_ 
,Action
,Transition_Steady_State
,Stream
,Stream_Lead
,Fixed_Variable
,Domain
,Pillar
,Account_Plan_Pilar
,Account_Plan_Project_Type)
VALUES('".mysql_real_escape_string($data[0])."','".mysql_real_escape_string($daa[1])."','".mysql_real_escape_string($data[2])."','".mysql_real_escape_string($data[3])."','".mysql_real_escape_string($data[4])."','".mysql_real_escape_string($data[5])."','".mysql_real_escape_string($data[6])."','".mysql_real_escape_string($data[7])."','".mysql_real_escape_string($data[8])."','".mysql_real_escape_string($data[9])."','".mysql_real_escape_string($data[10])."','".mysql_real_escape_string($data[11])."')"; 

mysql_query($import) or die(mysql_error());
```

Comment: Did you try `trim` ing your values?

Comment: do you mean trimming spaces in front and in back of the value or including the middle spaces?

Comment: you can also update your column using trim

Comment: @vhen trimming only front and back. i dont want middle spaces to be trimmed

Comment: @Progrock yes i did. not working

Comment: @krishnpatel can you please show me an example

Comment: update tablename set columanName =trim(columanName)

Comment: Obligatory comment to mention that you should stop using mysql_ functions, try mysqli or pdo instead.

Comment: @SharikDokadia     is it worked ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

From:

```
mysql_real_escape_string($data[0])
```

To:

```
mysql_real_escape_string(trim($data[0]))
```

Comment: this is not working. i want to trim only front and back spaces. i dont want middle spaces to be trimmed

Comment: @SharikDokadia then you don't understand the functionality of Php's trim (re. comment about middle spaces).